# Can't use sudo systemctl start myService

Tags: raspbian, systemd

Raspbian Buster Lite: Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

I am getting `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.` error when I am trying to `sudo systemctl start DisplayM`

I am trying to make a systemd service that starts on boot.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ cd /lib/systemd/system
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system $ sudo mkdir PPD_Display_m.service
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system/PPD_Display_m.service $ sudo nano DisplayM.service
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system/PPD_Display_m.service $ sudo chmod u+x /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system/PPD_Display_m.service $ sudo systemctl start DisplayM
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

Then I have tried this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/lib/systemd/system/PPD_Display_m.service $ sudo service DisplayM start
DisplayM: unrecognized service
```

This is what it's written in the service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Big_ppd_display_try1 service

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`Big_ppd_display_try1` is a exec file made by a make file from `Big_ppd_display_try1.cc`

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1248576 Aug 24 17:09 /var/www/html/4panel/Big_ppd_display_try1

Comment: Which version of raspbian are you using? Try to add `init=/bin/systemd` to your `/boot/cmdline.txt`, or better use raspbian buster.

Comment: I am using Raspbian Buster Lite: Linux raspberrypi 4.19.58-v7l+ #1245 SMP Fri Jul 12 17:31:45 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: So then I don't understand why the init is not `systemd`...

Comment: What's the output of `ls -la /sbin/init`?

Comment: I've added `init=/bin/systemd` to `/boot/cmdline.txt`, rebooted and I still get `System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down`

Comment: @jake -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 35260 Feb 14  2019 /sbin/init

Comment: That should be a symlink to `/lib/system/systemd` as mine looks like that `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 10 00:57 /sbin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd`. I don't know what is exactly wrong with you system. You could try to set the symlink...

Comment: I have no idea what is happening...

Comment: You could run `sudo rm /sbin/init; sudo ln -s /lib/systemd/systemd /sbin/init` but without any warranty.

Comment: Done it. Nothing happened.

Comment: Reboot after it.

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:/var/www/html/4panel $ sudo reboot

Broadcast message from root@raspberrypi (pts/0) (Sat Aug 24 19:51:44 2019):
The system is going down for reboot NOW!
Couldn't find an alternative telinit implementation to spawn.

Comment: I can't apparently.

Comment: I can't do `sudo reboot` nor `sudo poweroff`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98533/discussion-between-jake-and-bleah1).

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same issue on Raspbian Lite Buster, I'd like to echo [Jake's](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/92303/jake) comment on the OP:

- Add `init=/bin/systemd to your /boot/cmdline.txt`

As this solved it for me after a `sudo reboot`

Comment: Important "and that all parameters in cmdline.txt must be on the same line (no carriage returns)." -> https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/cmdline-txt.md (I guess @bleah1 was doing this wrong)